# guava: Multimap get objects from Collection

Tags: java, guava

I am quite new to using guava and I have tried to get objects from multimap values collection. I've tried using `Iterables.transform` but I don't know how to use it to get objects. Can you help me with kind of example? I appreciate every help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you want or what you've tried?  It's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: I have created Multimap<K, V> multimap and I have put some velues. If I want values then I just use multimap.get(key) and a have Collection<K> with objects. What I want is get objects from this collection.

Comment: @Martin Iterate on it? Just like any other collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Collection<V> values : multimap.values()){
  for(V value : values){
    value.doSomething();
  }
}
```